# Gradle dependency.. Kaltura Player & Google analytics incompatibility [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-analytics, kaltura

So, I´ve been messing around this issue for a day, until I found what it seems to be the problem, but now I can´t figure out how to solve it..

I have a proyect that uses Kaltura player sdk for android (https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android). I did some tests and it worked like a charm.. but then I tried to use it in my project and Gradle always fails when making the playerSDK with this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':playerSDK:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug'.
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../video-android/player-sdk-native-android/playerSDK/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/jni/lib/armeabi/libHLSPlayerSDK.so (No such file or directory)

After a day trying to figure out why this happens just in this particular proyect.. I found the problem occurs just when I add Google Analytics (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). Adding `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'` to the build.gradle (project) will make kaltura to throw this error on make proccess.

I´m not a gradle expert, in fact, I´m pretty new with it.. but I would like to know if there is some way to exclude this project dependency when building the playerSDK module.

This is the structure I have now:

```
  |
  \-- build.gradle(Project:SampleApp)
  \-- build.gradle(Module:App)
  \..
  \..
  \-- build.gradle(Module:playerSDK)
```

the project build has this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' //<<This classpath is the problem
    }
}
```

So, I need that classpath there to make google analytics work.. but for some strange reason, it brokes the playerSDK module.. Does anybody knows if there is a way to exclude that classpath for playerSDK module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I opened an issue on their github page and their response points me to try another branch, read here may help you: https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/issues/76

Answer (score 1):

Kaltura developer here. This issue was fixed in our develop branch, and will be released in a few days.